# Vuex how to pass state/getter in data prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I retrieved my data from database using axios under my vuex

```
const state = {
    giveaways: null
}

const actions = {
    getGiveAways : ({commit}) =>{

        axios({
            url : '/prod/api/thresholds_settings',
            method: 'post',
            data : {
            },
            config: 'JOSN'
        })
        .then(response=>{
            if(response.status == 200){
                //console.log(response.data.total_giveaways);
                commit('SET_GIVEAWAYS', response.data.total_giveaways)
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            if(error.response){
                console.log('something happened')
            }
        });
    }
}

const mutations = {
    SET_GIVEAWAYS : (state, obj)=>{
        state.giveaways = obj
    }

}

const getters = {
    doneGiveAways(state){
        return state.giveaways
    }
}
```

In my Dashboard.vue I have

```
import {mapState,mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default{
    data: () => ({
        cards: [],
        giveaways: ''
    }),
    computed:{
        ...mapState({
            Giveaway: state => state.Threshold.giveaways
        }),
        doneGiveAways(){
            return this.$store.getters.doneGiveAways
        }
    },
    ready(){
        //giveaways: this.Giveaways
        //console.log(this.Giveaways);          
    },
    created(){
        const self = this
        this.cards[0].result_val = 2
        this.cards[2].result_val = 2;

    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getGiveAways');
        console.log(this.giveaways);

    }
}
```

My problem is I need to pass the value from the mapState `Giveaway` to my returning data `giveaways: ''` so when page fires I can get the response value using `this.giveaways`. If I just call {{ Giveaway }} in my html it shows the value. But I need to make something like `this.giveaways = this.$store.state.Thresholds.giveaways`

Answer (score 2):

I would use Stephan-v's recommendation and delete the local copy of `giveaways`. But I don't know what your specific reason is for declaring an extra copy of `giveaways`, so here is a solution that will work:

In your `Dashboard.vue` add:

```
export default {
    ...
    watch: {
        Giveaway(value) {
            this.giveaways = value
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `giveaways` property from your data Object and rename the computed `doneGiveAways` to `giveaways` and you are done.

There is no need for a local component `giveaway` data property in this scenario.